# PHP Session + Memcached => Mysterious Data Format

Tags: php, memcached

I have been using memcached as session.save_handler for a while and everything is working 100% fine.

Then I try:

```
echo $mycache->get('memc.sess.key.o8el2bgk4k9s1mr723j1blrgs3');
```

to fetch one of the sessions and the output is very strange (a string with 108 characters):

```
MaiiA6iX7qlS0IZjTdr2I3w4axNTp7H2IYcH-SAficGw5ZKIcMQ0BE2kFnsm4xHMk3KAJo9kOwmRTSBOPdPAC-m5L9CkWnYPONqujt5m0c8.
```

What format is this string in? For your info, here's the memcached configuration in phpinfo():

- Directive Local Value Master Value
- memcached.compression_factor  1.3 1.3
- memcached.compression_threshold   2000    2000
- memcached.compression_type    fastlz  fastlz
- memcached.serializer  php php
- memcached.sess_binary 0   0
- memcached.sess_lock_wait  150000  150000
- memcached.sess_locking    1   1
- memcached.sess_prefix memc.sess.key.  memc.sess.key.

So it should have been in this format:

```
user_name|s:5:"guest";user_id|s:1:"3";user_level|s:2:"-1";
```

instead of the strange string.

Note: I am using memcached + php-memcached. Not memcache, and not php-memcache. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you don't have compression by default in your memcache instance, but the session handler use it anyway. Can you try `$mycache->get('your_session_key', MEMCACHE_COMPRESSED)`?

Comment: @MathieuImbert It's memcached, not memcache, so the commands are different. I tried $mycache->setOption(Memcached::OPT_COMPRESSION, true); (and false) and the result was the same.

Comment: Oh sorry about that, I didn't realize it was memcached. The compression flag was my only guess. It can be some builtin compression / encoding inside memcached session handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find the culprit! suhosin.session.encrypt.

p.s. I am fetching data from memcached directly, because I am testing WebSocket and one has to pass the session ID using JS manually. Then I need to get the session variables for that ID by myself :D

Comment: Thanks - that was a real time saver as soon as we've found the issue. To capture memcache traffic on the fly: `tshark -i eth1 -n -R memcache -Tfields -e tcp.srcport -e tcp.dstport -e memcache.command -e memcache.key -e memcache.value  -e memcache.response  'port 11211'`

Answer (score 1):

PHP Sessions are encoded/decoded with their own functions - see [session_decode](http://php.net/session_decode).

Comment: The problem: it should have been user_name|s:5:"guest";user_id|s:1:"3";user_level|s:2:"-1"; instead of that strange string.